# Grouping a List by two fields in Java

Tags: java

I have a Student class. It contains the city, name and country fields.I have an ArrayList that contains Student objects. What I want to do is to group student objects with city and country fields. I can do it with one attribute like this
But how can i do both name and country? Do you have any idea? I am using java 7.

```
for (Student student: studentList) {
    Long key  = student.country;
        if(map.containsKey(key)){
            List<Student> list = map.get(key);
            list.add(student);

        }else{
            List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
            list.add(student);
            map.put(key, list);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some key type which allows you to support multiple values, for example:

```
List<Object> key = Arrays.asList(city, country);
```

Replace your `Long key ...` line with this (and update `map`'s type accordingly), e.g.

```
Map<List<Object>, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

(`List<Object>` is actually not a great choice here, it's merely expedient: I'd use something like a specific `CityAndCountry` class, defined for example using Google's [`AutoValue`](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value))

Comment: Thank you very much.I will define key class to solve this situation.I am sure it will solve the problem

Comment: if(map.containsKey(key)) line is not working, always else block is running

Comment: @hagi10 did you override `equals` and `hashCode` in your key class?